# resize image on zend-framework

Tags: image, zend-framework, resize

I wandered is some special tool for image resize in Zend Framework?
Or I should use code like this:

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
try {
    $upload->receive();
} catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}
$im_org = imageCreateFromJpeg($upload);
$im_bg = imageCreateTrueColor(300, 300);
imageCopyResampled($im_bg, $im_org, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 300, imageSX($im_org), imageSY($im_org));
imageJpeg($im_bg, "pict/" . $id . "_bg.jpg", 100);
imagedestroy($im_org);
imagedestroy($im_bg);
```

Thank you!

Comment: try some open source image resize library ex phpThumb() http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [Zend_Filter_ImageSize](https://github.com/polycaster/Zend_Filter_ImageSize)

**Most simple example:**

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Filter/ImageSize.php';
$filter = new Zend_Filter_ImageSize();
$output = $filter->setHeight(100)
    ->setWidth(200)
    ->filter('./orig.jpg');

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$fh = fopen($output, 'r');
fpassthru($fh);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a solid library such as [class.upload.php from verot.net](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm).

It should easily integrate into Zend Framework, you can find a [more complex example integration on this blog post](http://blog.paladise.ch/dynamic-image-resize-zend-framework-integration/).